# Does embedding vector graphics in apps makes sense?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, graphics, vector-graphics

I wonder whether it makes sense to put in my iOS app vector graphics. I wonder whether they could be drawn by system faster or not (from raster - which I can't scale too much - equivalents). Maybe this depends on the complexity of an image ?

Does it makes sense ? To have vector graphics, and don't worry about scaling images between iPad screen and iPhone screen ?

What's the preferred way to embed things like logos, and icons in iOS apps ?

Comment: Since you're asking "what's the preferred way...", any answers will be opinion-based which isn't really a good fit for StackOverflow. You might try asking this question on the Programmer stack exchange.